# How to push the testng result from jenkins to ALM octane

Tags: selenium, testng, alm

I have integrated ALM OCtane with Jenkins but unable to push the reports to ALM octane as there is no plugin present in post build actions dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it in multiple ways,

1. Use Jenkins plugin
   https://plugins.jenkins.io/hp-application-automation-tools-plugin/
2. Use the Test Result Collection tool jar file provided by MicroFocus.
   https://github.com/MicroFocus/octane-collection-tool/releases. You need to work with your Octane admin to create an API Access key with the required permission to publish the test result. BTW, the result file should be in JUnit XML style.
3. Write custom utility to push the test results to Octane